Как можно добавить значения переменных в бд с помощью sqlite3?
import sqlite3

data = open("data.txt", "r", encoding="u8")
data = data.readlines()
con = sqlite3.connect("myproject.db")
for i in range(len(data)):
    s = data[i].split()
    name = " ".join(s[:3])
    raiting = int(s[-1])
    query = """
    INSERT INTO players(id, name, raiting) VALUES(i, name, raiting)
    """
    con.execute(query)



sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: i.

Что с этим делать? Может, где-то понятно написано про структуру со знаками "?"?

Уточните, какмим образом в вашей строке должны оказать значения переменных?

То есть? Не совсем понимаю Вас

У вас query это просто строчка с текстом. Этот текст у вас никак не связан с другими переменными или их значениями.

Все, исправил. Теперь должно быть луче
